# How do I test a controller to ensure that the authorize filter is applied to it with the correct role?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-assertions

I have a controller in the admin section of my site and it is decorated with the Authorize filter with the role set to admin.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class SubscriberController : Controller
```

This works great but I'd like to create a unit test to ensure that the filter is not removed. I've got this far, to validate that the Authorize filter is present.

```
        typeof(SubscriberController).Should()
            .BeDecoratedWith<AuthorizeAttribute>(
                "Subscriber controller users must be admins");
```

How can I validate the Roles argument? I am using Fluent Assertion 1.7.1.1.

It is possible now in Fluent Assertion v2:

```
    typeof(SubscriberController).Should()
        .BeDecoratedWith<AuthorizeAttribute>(a => a.Roles.Contains("Admin"),
            "Subscriber controller users must be admins");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that isn't possible now - [Testing Arguments of Attributes](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/discussions/279305)

You can up this thread and ask about progress.

Comment: Thanks for answering... pitty it isn't implemented yet, just validating that visitors are authorized isn't good enough unfortunately, don't want customers changing their own subscription.

Comment: We should be able to come up with a syntax for it. I'll create a item on the backlog for 2.0.0.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, that would be great. It would fill quite a large hole in ASP.NET MVC automated testing that could only be overcome by resorting to full stack integration testing.

Comment: It's in the public beta of version 2.0 http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/releases/view/82423